# Generating the same random number from a string across clients

Tags: actionscript-3, random, multiplayer

I'm building a multiplayer desktop Air game, and I need to generate a random number that is the same in both clients.

I've been reading a bit about how other games do it, and apparently if I have the same seed in both clients, the random output will be the same.

However I never tried to do this, no idea where to begin.

How does it work?, how does this string (let's same player name) assures me that the random output in both clients will be the same?.

Comment: `a random number that is the same` is not a random number. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: A random number that is the same across clients. I want to generate randomness in a multiplayer game, of course I can't call Math.random() in both clients since both will produce different results and screw up the sync.

Comment: You might try looking at the algorithm called Xorshift. It generates seeded random numbers (the seed is int , not String) and it's pretty simple to implement.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those things that is conceptually easy but in practice can be quite hard.

Conceptually, a *pseudo-random number generator* (PRNG) is an algorithm that uses its current state information to generate a new state, and then returns to you some function of that state. For example, *linear congruential generators* (LCGs) were a popular choice for many decades because they're relatively fast and easy to implement.  LCGs are recurrence relationships of the form:

```
R(i+1) = (a * R(i) + b) % m
```

where `R(i)` is the i<sup>th</sup> integer-valued "random" number in the sequence, and `a`, `b`, and `m` are carefully selected integer constants. Setting the seed means giving the PRNG an initial state, i.e., assigning a value for `R(0)` to kickstart the process.  Modern PRNGs generally use multiple recurrence functions to maintain a multiple integers in their state space and return a single integer value based on some function of the entire state, but the basic principle still applies—starting from the same state will yield exactly the same sequence of return values for a sequence of calls to the PRNG.

Now for the practical side of things.  This means two players will get the same sequence of outcomes if their games are synchronized—they start from the same seed and go through the same sequence of events so their PRNGs are always in the same state for each decision they make along the game path.  However, making different choices will lead to the PRNG outcomes being used for different purposes, and quite possibly to using different quantities of PRNG outcomes.  One choice by the player might cause the program to draw 2 PRNs where an alternative choice would draw 3. The games will now be out of sync, and yield different results for subsequent PRNG-based outcomes, which usually drives the game paths further out of sync.

Maintaining synchronization of PRNG usage is very hard to accomplish in practice.  One possible solution is to maintain multiple instances of PRNG state, one for each distinct use case. For instance, a particular battle would always be started in the same PRNG state, but that requires anticipating and maintaining a whole bunch of independent PRNG sequences.  Another solution is to pre-generate all entities and all of their attributes up-front, in essence tattooing them with every random choice or option they *may* be involved in and hauling out the results when and if they get into those circumstances.  Both approaches quickly become a logistical headache.

Comment: So how do companies do it in real world games?. In my case I only need a "random" number from 1 to 10. I guess one cheap way to do it would be to always sum something like 7, and then start from the beginning again. Something like: 7-4-1-8-5-2-9-6-3... etc. Makes sense?.

Comment: Can't tell you how companies do it in real-world games.  1) As indicated above, it's generally complex and the trade-offs between alternatives would depend entirely on the specifics of your case; and 2) it would be proprietary info.  What I've described above are the principles, and two techniques used by people in the field of analytical simulation modeling to achieve synchronization across models and scenarios.  If you want to know more, google "common random numbers".

Answer (score 4):

I've built multiplayer games. The way this is usually handled is that the server handles details like this and the data is sent to all players.

If you are doing peer-to-peer with no server involved then one player acts as "server" or "host", generates whatever game details you need (obstacle layout, etc.) and then passes that information to the peer(s). The player acting as "server" has no advantage. Its "client" code is not privy to any special treatment (except data transfer speed). The "server" also maintains game state in the event of lag. It determines when the game is "over" etc.

Depending on how you are handling advertising the game on a network, that will determine who is "host". Post more details about that if you want to discuss it. In a simple set up, one player decides to "host" a game, it is advertised on the network and someone joins, and establishes a p2p connection with the "host". With larger games it gets more complicated since you want to handle the condition of the "host" player dropping out. The way this is handled is that ALL players maintain the state of the game so someone else can step up if the "host" drops.

There is **a lot** of messaging between peers to maintain game state. With turn-based games this is pretty easy but with dynamic games it gets quite complicated.

Your idea of both clients generating the same data set, while perhaps logical, is not workable.

Comment: The game is turn based and deterministic, I don't see the need of a server acting as managing entity of the sorts. And even if "server handles details like this and the data is sent to all players." is not really answering the question, since I still have no idea how to work with this seed and how a seed generates predetermined and identical random values across clients.